logical replication - who is managing replication slots created automatically during initial sync
I have seen that logical replication slots created automatically by Postgres during initial sync (a slot per table), are marked as "wal_status = lost" and "active = false".

Who is responsible for removing those faulty replication slots?
Can a slot with "wal_status = lost" recover from this state?
Do I need to drop the subscription in such a case?
Are those replication slots that synchronize a single table each, use a connection from "max_connections" and replication slot from "max_logical_replication_slots"?
If I sync many tables will it be better to increase the number of max_logical_replication_slots or to have some of the tables "wait" for other tables to complete and release the replication slot for them to use.

I'm using Postgres 15.2
slot_name   plugin  slot_type   datoid  database    temporary   active  active_pid  xmin    catalog_xmin    restart_lsn confirmed_flush_lsn wal_status  safe_wal_size   two_phase
pg_8034820_sync_8033089_7371741997992267844 pgoutput    logical 16707   aaa_db  FALSE   FALSE   NULL    NULL    295098502   NULL    D9/EB7317B0 lost    NULL    FALSE
pg_6839631_sync_6837833_7371741997992267844 pgoutput    logical 16707   aaa_db  FALSE   FALSE   NULL    NULL    288349892   NULL    D2/80068A78 lost    NULL    FALSE

Thanks!

Seems your initialisation got problems. Those replication slots is supposed to have value True for column Temporary and they are automatically dropped once the initialisation succeeds for a table. But in your case wal_status showing as lost means some WAL required for sync already removed before sending it to subscriber. Those slots are no more useful and you may drop them manually.
If you don't see any row with column active=true and temporary=false means you don't have any active replication in sync. If that's the case you may try ,

Increasing max_replication_slots and max_wal_senders
OR
Creating separate publication and replication slot for bigger tables or tables receiving very high writes.
OR
Increasing max_slot_wal_keep_size or set to -1(no limit) until
you completes initialisation(Need to have an eye on the disk where
WALs are written)

